# How can i hide dbo. schema from tables ,views procs,

Tags: sql-server

I want to hide or disable  dbo schema name  from mssql 2014    (ssms 2017)

[image]

Comment: It's not a feature on SSMS. Also, knowing the schema name is *really* important; I don't know why you would *want* to hide it.

Comment: Obviously, the OP wants to hide it for convenience as it is the default schema and is probably the only schema in use in their DB. So it is messy, unnecessary and distracting. It should be an option which you can turn off if you don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide dbo schema objects, you can apply filter as given below. But, if you want to not to show dbo schema prefix, it cannot be done. All the tables, views are shown with corresponding schema. It is helpful always. You cannot hide the schema prefix in SSMS.

You can right click `Tables` folder in the object explorer and choose `Filter > Filter settings` and set up filter as given below. Now, the dbo schema tables are filtered out, in the Tables folder.

[image: Filter Settings]

Comment: If this *is* the right answer, I would suggest the OP has worded it poorly. I read it as the OP wants the schema name to not be shown, so instead of `dbo.MyTable` just `MyTable`, *not* the filter the objects on the `dbo` schema out on the object explorer.

Comment: @Larnu, understood. I thought that OP wants to hide dbo schema objects. may be OP can comment if this is fine for him. I will update answer accordingly.